# How do I read data from a text file, then write a new text file with new calculations and use my subclass methods for calculations?

Tags: c#

First of all I would like to know how I might be able to perform calculations for a text file with data such as:
Type  Product Price Quantity
regular,bread,2.00,2
regular,milk,2.00,3

I want to perform calculations such as getting the total cost for each one, for each line and then write the results to a new file.

Please note I need it formatted in the structure where Grocery Item is the base class and PurchasedItem and FreshItem are both subclasses, so I need to use the methods on each subclass for calculating.
Note I have tried using test values instead of reading text file values and it seems I cannot retrieve the method from FreshItem Subclass but it works with methods on the PurchasedItem class (i guess this questions is for later, I want to make sure im using a compatible writeAllLines method first that can use subclass methods)
The below sample has missing constructors and is just an example layout

```
class GroceryItem 


{
public void writeFile()
        {
            List<string> lines = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines("groceries.txt"));

            //regular item cost calculator
            PurchasedItem purchasedItem = new PurchasedItem(50,1); //testing to return value to print into the write out file
            double cost = purchasedItem.regularCost();
            lines.Add(Convert.ToString(cost));

            //fresh item cost calculation here
            double purchaseCost = purchasedItem.freshItemCost(10,1); //<<<<<<============Trying to add the method from the sub-subclass freshItemCost()

            //total items calculation here

            //total cost calculation here

            // Reads all lines from the file and puts them into the list.
            lines.Add("Grocery for you"); // You can add new lines now.
            lines.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            File.WriteAllLines("c:\\MicrosoftVisual\\invoice.txt", lines);
        }
public class PurchasedItem : GroceryItem //inheriting properties from class GroceryItem
        {
                public double regularCost() //method from cost of regular
            {
                return this.price * this.quantity * 1.1; //workout out cost  for purchases including GST
            }
        }
public class FreshItem : PurchasedItem    //Inheriting properties from class Purchased Item
        {
public double freshItemCost(double w, double p) //method to get cost of fresh item
                {
                    return this.weight * this.price; //workout cost of the fresh item excluding GST
                }
```

Comment: Well, as not every `PurchasedItem` actually is a `FreshItem`, it surely does not have a `freshItemCost`. You´d ave to create an instance of `FreshItem` instead of `PurchasedItem` in order to call the member: `FreshItem purchasedItem = new FreshItem(50,1)`:

Comment: omg thanks for pointing that out, for some reason I was trying to add the instance within the fresh class instead of the base class, I only just started OOP learning last week so probably a newbie mistake... ok now that the subclass thing is solved... how do I make calculations on what I am reading?

Comment: I don´t understand your question. Were do you want to perform a calculation? And what do you want to calculate? Isn´t the `freshItemCost`-method doing what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to get started :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication108
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = "groceries.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GroceryItem grocery = new GroceryItem();
            grocery.ReadFile(FILENAME);

        }
    }
    class GroceryItem
    {
        public static List<GroceryItem> items = new List<GroceryItem>();

        public string _type { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        public decimal price { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal weight { get; set; }

        public void ReadFile(string filename)
        {
            string line = "";
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();

                if(line.Length > 0)
                {
                    string[] splitArray = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                    //regular item cost calculator

                    _type = splitArray[0];
                    name = splitArray[1];
                    PurchasedItem purchasedItem = new PurchasedItem(splitArray); //testing to return value to print into the write out file
                    items.Add(purchasedItem);
                }
            }

        }
        public class PurchasedItem : GroceryItem //inheriting properties from class GroceryItem
        {
            public PurchasedItem(string[] splitArray)
            {
                this._type = splitArray[0];
                this.name = splitArray[1];
                this.quantity = int.Parse(splitArray[2]);
                this.price = decimal.Parse(splitArray[3]);
            }
            public decimal regularCost() //method from cost of regular
            {
                return this.price * this.quantity * (decimal)1.1; //workout out cost  for purchases including GST
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is how i tried to integrate it, i tried changing the items to string otherwise it would not let me add my method to perform the calculation for the grocery price, however if i changed it or not, when i try adding everything together it seems to come up with an error, here is the code so far:

Sorry that it's probably long and has a bit of unnecessary stuff in: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pBrXwz